# C programming language , Making useful programs

Tags: c

I have learned C for 2 months, I understand all the basics.
Pointers, Structs,Unions. all the basics in short. 
But the only problem is.. that all the tutorials online just show how to make console program.
How do I start writing a useful program ? 

Thanks !

Comment: This is primarily-opinion based.

Comment: Try to think of a useful program yourself then challenge yourself to write in in C! Get imaginative and creative. That's how all programs are born!

Comment: Look at the source code of other projects. Look at the structure they have, the naming convention they follow and how they put things together. Then might have an idea.

Comment: If you mean something with a GUI, you probably want to move beyond C - otherwise, it's reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Console programs can't be useful?

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone runs into this problem early on in their programming adventure. I know I did. I think the best advice is just to find something that itches, and scratch it. Think of a problem you can solve. When you have one, you will more than likely be forced to learn a few new things and then you are on your way.

It doesn't last long, by the way. As long as you persist in solving your problem, you will learn, and the more you learn, them more problems you will be able to solve.

Godspeed!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure out something you'd like to do, then find an open-source project to get involved with, such as Apache or FreeBSD or whatever.  Beware that the learning curve might be steep and you might end up doing absolute low-level monkey work (can you say documentation) but stick with it and you'll end up doing something "useful"